# return of Void Function in C on a vector

Tags: c, function, vector, reference, void

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

void mult (int v[], int N, int g);

int main() {
    int i, v[N], x;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("Inserirt value in %d position: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    printf("Insert value to moltiply each vector value: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    mult(v,N,x);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mult (int v[], int N, int g){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        v[i]=g*(v[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't know how it doesn't work, maybe there's a problem on void function, sorry for the stupid question, but I'm studying it at university and the teacher said to write this program using the void function without the return into the function declaration.
Thanx everybody.

Comment: What do you mean saying that it does not work?

Answer (score 3):

`N` is defined as a macro which gets replaced by the preprocessor before compiling the source code.

For instance, the prototype for the `mult` function will look to the compiler like the following:

```
void mult (int v[], int 5, int g);
```

producing compile-time errors.

Use a different name either for the macro or the parameter.